# Site is refusing to treat relative URLs as secure

Tags: apache, ssl, openssl

I have a PHP app running on an Apache/RHEL setup.  I have the SSL certificate installed and it all checks out okay.  I am using the .htaccess file to redirect to 'https://' with this snippet

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

All assets on the site use relative URLs for assets, however some of them are served with 'https://' and some are served with 'http://'.
In Chrome, the stylesheets and javascripts are blocked using a relative URL.  If you visit the stylesheet directly (with the https://) it loads just fine and even gives the green company name in the URL bar.

Some of the images return '302 Found' and looking at the request information via the Chrome dev tools I can see the Request Url is 'http://' while further down in the response headers section I see under location 'https://'.  It seems to only do this with some images and some it doesn't - I can't find a pattern. If I visit some of the problem images directly they, again, load just fine.

Is that .htaccess redirect interfering with how the assets are served? I've restarted browsers, cleared cache, etc.  I'm at a complete loss.  I can provide more details about the setup if they are necessary.  Thanks in advance.

*edit*
Just to clarify - this isn't an issue with a single absolute URL in the document giving an insecure content warning.  Relative URLs are being accessed by 'http://' despite being a relative URL.

Comment: Why have you tagged this question with [php] tag?

Comment: What other redirects do you have there

Comment: Something is still using a absolute url, check the generated HTML/CSS.

Comment: @hank One absolute URL would not explain why 10 assets referenced by relative URLs would fail to be served via https://

Comment: @Anigel No other redirects setup at all.

Comment: Can you provide a url or html source so we can test